# Trying to create a matching game in flash with actionscript3, running into undefined property errors

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I'm trying to create a flash matching game where students have drag and drop an item into a target, while allowing them to do it wrong before they have to check their results. I used this tutorial (as I know very little about flash, trying to learn).

http://www.danfergusdesign.com/classfiles/oldClasses/VCB324-richMedia2/exercises/matchingGame.php

I seem to be getting errors around line 85/86 stating "Scene 1, Layer 'Action Layer', Frame 1, Line 86  1120: Access of undefined property dropZone1_mc." on MANY MANY lines referring to the the _mc entries. Not sure where to go from here, tried QUITE a lot of different bits. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My code is as follows:

```
right_mc.visible = false;
wrong_mc.visible = false;

var orig1X:Number = item1_mc.x;
var orig1Y:Number = item1_mc.y;
var orig2X:Number = item2_mc.x;
var orig2Y:Number = item2_mc.y;
var orig3X:Number = item3_mc.x;
var orig3Y:Number = item3_mc.y;
var orig4X:Number = item4_mc.x;
var orig4Y:Number = item4_mc.y;
var orig5X:Number = item5_mc.x;
var orig5Y:Number = item5_mc.y;
var orig6X:Number = item6_mc.x;
var orig6Y:Number = item6_mc.y;
var orig7X:Number = item7_mc.x;
var orig7Y:Number = item7_mc.y;
var orig8X:Number = item8_mc.x;
var orig8Y:Number = item8_mc.y;
var orig9X:Number = item9_mc.x;
var orig9Y:Number = item9_mc.y;
var orig10X:Number = item10_mc.x;
var orig10Y:Number = item10_mc.y;
var orig11X:Number = item11_mc.x;
var orig11Y:Number = item11_mc.y;
var orig12X:Number = item12_mc.x;
var orig12Y:Number = item12_mc.y;
var orig13X:Number = item13_mc.x;
var orig13Y:Number = item13_mc.y;

item1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);
item1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, itemRelease);
item2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);
item2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, itemRelease);
item3_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);
item3_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, itemRelease);
item4_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);
item4_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, itemRelease);
item5_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);
item5_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, itemRelease);
item6_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);
item6_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, itemRelease);
item7_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);
item7_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, itemRelease);
item8_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);
item8_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, itemRelease);
item9_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);
item9_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, itemRelease);
item10_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);
item10_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, itemRelease);
item11_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);
item11_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, itemRelease);
item12_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);
item12_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, itemRelease);
item13_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);
item13_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, itemRelease);

done_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkAnswers);
reset_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reset);

item1_mc.buttonMode = true;
item2_mc.buttonMode = true;
item3_mc.buttonMode = true;
item4_mc.buttonMode = true;
item5_mc.buttonMode = true;
item6_mc.buttonMode = true;
item7_mc.buttonMode = true;
item8_mc.buttonMode = true;
item9_mc.buttonMode = true;
item10_mc.buttonMode = true;
item11_mc.buttonMode = true;
item12_mc.buttonMode = true;
item13_mc.buttonMode = true;

function dragTheObject(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var item:MovieClip = MovieClip(event.target);
    item.startDrag();
    var topPos:uint = this.numChildren - 1;
    this.setChildIndex(item, topPos);
}

function itemRelease(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var thisItem:MovieClip = MovieClip(event.target);
    thisItem.stopDrag();
    if (dropZone1_mc.hitTestPoint(thisItem.x,thisItem.y))
    {
        thisItem.x = dropZone1_mc.x;
        thisItem.y = dropZone1_mc.y;
    }
    else if (dropZone2_mc.hitTestPoint(thisItem.x,thisItem.y))
    {
        thisItem.x = dropZone2_mc.x;
        thisItem.y = dropZone2_mc.y;
    }
    else if (dropZone3_mc.hitTestPoint(thisItem.x,thisItem.y))
    {
        thisItem.x = dropZone3_mc.x;
        thisItem.y = dropZone3_mc.y;
    }
    else if (dropZone4_mc.hitTestPoint(thisItem.x,thisItem.y))
    {
        thisItem.x = dropZone4_mc.x;
        thisItem.y = dropZone4_mc.y;
    }
    else if (dropZone5_mc.hitTestPoint(thisItem.x,thisItem.y))
    {
        thisItem.x = dropZone5_mc.x;
        thisItem.y = dropZone5_mc.y;
    }
    else if (dropZone6_mc.hitTestPoint(thisItem.x,thisItem.y))
    {
        thisItem.x = dropZone6_mc.x;
        thisItem.y = dropZone6_mc.y;
    }
    else if (dropZone7_mc.hitTestPoint(thisItem.x,thisItem.y))
    {
        thisItem.x = dropZone7_mc.x;
        thisItem.y = dropZone7_mc.y;
    }
    else if (dropZone8_mc.hitTestPoint(thisItem.x,thisItem.y))
    {
        thisItem.x = dropZone8_mc.x;
        thisItem.y = dropZone8_mc.y;
    }
    else if (dropZone9_mc.hitTestPoint(thisItem.x,thisItem.y))
    {
        thisItem.x = dropZone9_mc.x;
        thisItem.y = dropZone9_mc.y;
    }
    else if (dropZone10_mc.hitTestPoint(thisItem.x,thisItem.y))
    {
        thisItem.x = dropZone10_mc.x;
        thisItem.y = dropZone10_mc.y;
    }
    else if (dropZone1_mc.hitTestPoint(thisItem.x,thisItem.y))
    {
        thisItem.x = dropZone11_mc.x;
        thisItem.y = dropZone11_mc.y;
    }
    else if (dropZone12_mc.hitTestPoint(thisItem.x,thisItem.y))
    {
        thisItem.x = dropZone12_mc.x;
        thisItem.y = dropZone12_mc.y;
    }
    else if (dropZone13_mc.hitTestPoint(thisItem.x,thisItem.y))
    {
        thisItem.x = dropZone13_mc.x;
        thisItem.y = dropZone13_mc.y;
    }// to eliminate snap-back comment out the next three else statements:
    /*else if (thisItem==item1_mc) {
            event.target.x = orig1X;
            event.target.y = orig1Y;
        } else if (thisItem==item2_mc) {
             event.target.x = orig2X;
             event.target.y = orig2Y;
        } else {
             event.target.x = orig3X;
             event.target.y = orig3Y;*/
}


function checkAnswers(event:MouseEvent):void
{
if (dropZone1_mc.hitTestPoint(item1_mc.x,item1_mc.y) && 
dropZone2_mc.hitTestPoint(item2_mc.x,item2_mc.y) && 
dropZone3_mc.hitTestPoint(item3_mc.x,item3_mc.y) && 
dropZone4_mc.hitTestPoint(item4_mc.x,item4_mc.y) && 
dropZone5_mc.hitTestPoint(item5_mc.x,item5_mc.y) && 
dropZone6_mc.hitTestPoint(item6_mc.x,item6_mc.y) && 
dropZone7_mc.hitTestPoint(item7_mc.x,item7_mc.y) && 
dropZone8_mc.hitTestPoint(item8_mc.x,item8_mc.y) && 
dropZone9_mc.hitTestPoint(item9_mc.x,item9_mc.y) && 
dropZone10_mc.hitTestPoint(item10_mc.x,item10_mc.y)  && 
dropZone11_mc.hitTestPoint(item11_mc.x,item11_mc.y)  && 
dropZone12_mc.hitTestPoint(item12_mc.x,item12_mc.y)  && 
dropZone13_mc.hitTestPoint(item13_mc.x,item13_mc.y))
{
    wrong_mc.visible = false;
    right_mc.visible = true;
}
else
{
    wrong_mc.visible = true;
    right_mc.visible = false;
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please consider increasing the quality of the site by shortening the code down to the useful part required to reproduce/understand the problem.

Comment: You don't need to put the whole code, just the part where the error is fired. Try to verify your `dropZone1_mc` object, it's name, type, ...

Comment: You really should have a look at OO programming, it will save you a lot of headaches and will make your code easier to read and debug.

Answer (score 0):

Double check every letter in `dropZone1_mc` movieClip name because it appears that some movieClip names in as3 code and movieClip names on the stage do not match

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reason why this could be happening.But the prominent ones are

1.dropZone1_mc could have been misspelled or not named at all

2.It could have been removed by a removeChild statement or added by a addChild to another movie clip during execution ,because of which it isn't directly accessible anymore.

3.It may be on a different frame when it reaches this line of code(reading your question this seems very unlikely)

4.Or it may be inside another movie clip or graphic from the beginning.

without looking at your .fla file we can only speculate

I would advice you to reduce the number of variables in your code

```
var posX,posY,currentDragObject;
function dragTheObject(e:MouseEvent){
   currentdragObject=e.currentTarget as MovieClip;
   posX=currentdragObject.x;
   posY=currentdragObject.y;
   currentdragObject.startDrag();
   //add the mouse up listener on the stage
   addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,itemRelease);
} 
function itemRelease(e:MouseEvent){
    //removelistener from stage
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,itemRelease);
    currentdragObject.stopDrag()
    if (hittestpoint is true){
      //do what you do for the right answer

   }
   else{
      //snapping back if wrong
      currentdragObject.x=posX;
      currentdragObject.y= posY;
   }

}
```